If x then do y?
I have a spreadsheet where I'm already using a IFERROR(VLOOKUP function to automatically input data based on the date it was entered. However, on one of the columns, this doesn't work. I want to be able to search the column and put in a date and if it says group have the function fill in with a checkmark and if it says individual have it check in that spot.
What I'm trying to achieve:

The data set/source:

Right now it's just blank and I'm manually putting in the "x" to mark whether it was group or individual and sometimes i forget to change it. if it could automatically input that would be great. i figured out the vlookup function by just looking at an example. not sure how to get this solved.

" I want to be able to search the column and put in a date and if it says group have the function fill in with a checkmark and if it says individual" If what says "group"/"individual"? You want to put a checkmark where? Your question is not clear to me.

I included photos but they didnt show up the way i wanted them to. again im not super good at tech so even asking this here was confusing to me

the photo attached named function sheet is what i want it to present as and the photo named data set is what i'm pulling from

Got it! I didn't realize there were two pictures. Edited to help others.

if(vlookup(<date cell>, <data set range>, 3, false) = 'Group', 'x', '') should do the job unless I'm misunderstanding. Copy and Paste and change to Individual for the next cell down.

that sounds perfect! I'll try that!

okay see that should work but its giving me an error message let me keep playing with it some more

Get the =vlookup() working first so you can have it return Group, Individual or an error. Then toss the whole thing into the =If() formula to make the x. Also make sure that <data set range> is the full range of your data set (that it starts with your date column and ends with the column that holds your group/individual values) like Sheet5!C1:D50000 or whatever.

This is the formula i'm using to put in the time on the time in cell above: =IFERROR(VLOOKUP(B26, Data!B:AC, 2,FALSE), " "). so basically get this to where it will return group in the cell, then take the whole thing and put it in something else?

okay so this pulled over where it says group in the cell now =IFERROR(VLOOKUP(B26,Data!B:R,3,false))  so i take that and then change it to =IF(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(B26,Data!B:R,3,false)), 'Group', 'x', ' ')?

Close. It will look like =IF(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(B26,Data!B:R,3,false))='Group', 'x','') as the first parameter in the =IF() formula is a condition (something that returns TRUE or FALSE.

it's still giving me an error message, does it make a difference if its in excel or google sheets?

@JNevill those quotes should be double quotes: =IF(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(B26,Data!B:R,3,false))="Group", "x","")
